# Selecting next input field (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, input

I have a jQuery UI slider. All works great using this code:

**Form**

```
<div class="ui-slide" id="test_div" min="1" max="20" inc="1"></div>
<input readonly="readonly" name="padding" id="padding" type="text" value="5" />
```

This is the JavaScript code that I use to get the value of the textfield:

**JS Code**

```
$('div.ui-slide').each(function(i){

    if( $(this).attr('min') != undefined && $(this).attr('max') != undefined ) {

        $(this).slider( { 
                        min: parseInt($(this).attr('min')), 
                        max: parseInt($(this).attr('max')), 
                        value: parseInt($(this).next("input").val()),
                        step: parseInt($(this).attr('inc')) ,
                        slide: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( this ).next("input").val(ui.value);
                        }
                    });

        $(this).removeAttr('min').removeAttr('max').removeAttr('inc');

    }

});
```

**The Issue:**

I need to place both the slider and the textfield inside a table, specifically each in there own "td". When I do this I can no longer retrieve the values of the textfield using the above JS code.

```
<table><tbody><tr>
<td><div class="ui-slide" id="test_div" min="1" max="20" inc="1"></div></td>
<td><input readonly="readonly" name="padding" id="padding" type="text" value="5" /></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Chrome development tools gives me this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

I figured it has to do with this line of code:

```
value: parseInt($(this).next("input").val()),
```

I am unsure though how to get the value of the next "input" once it is inside a table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of overusing `next()` find the proper input element in table row:

```
parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find('input[name="padding"]').val()),
```

jQuery docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That solved it. Got it working using value: parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find('input').val()),